# Axios.all, how to configure axios wait time to mitigate hung up?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await, axios

My application uses an internal webservice for fetching data, i have a job which creates approx 500 requests which getsfired async to complete the fetch operation.
I make use of Axios, by creating an array of axios promises and then resolving them using using Axios.all();

It works fine until some 200 requests but post that i get socket hung up, however on the server side i see the requests are being processed.

How to configure axios to set custom time out, or is it a better idea to splice my promises array and then run them as multiple batches ?

> Source code

```
let getAxiosPromiseArray = (urlList) => {
    var axiosArrayofPromise = [];

    return new Promise ( (resolve, reject) => {


        try {
            urlList.forEach ( (URL) => {
                axiosArrayofPromise.push(axios.get(URL));
            });
            resolve(axiosArrayofPromise);

        }
        catch (err) {
            reject("There is a problem getting Axios array of promises " + err);
        }

    })
}

async function processAxiosPromises (PromiseArray) {
    try {
        var results = []
        results =  await axios.all(PromiseArray);
        return results;
    }
    catch(err) {
        throw("There was a problem resolving promises array (Axios) " + err);
    }


}


getallID().then ( (urlList) => {
    return getAxiosPromiseArray(urlList);
}).then( (AxiosPromises) => {
    return processAxiosPromises(AxiosPromises);
}).then ((resultData) => {
    console.log(resultData);
});
```

> Error

```
There was a problem resolving promises array (Axios) Error: socket hang up
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, that pair of functions `getAxiosPromiseArray()` and `processAxiosPromises()` needs fixing.

Your `new Promise()` construction is unnecessary. You can simply `return Promise.all(arrayofPromise)` (or axios.all(...) if you must) and do away with the other function.

Renaming the remaining function to something meaningful, you would end up with eg :

```
let getData = (urlList) => {
    return Promise.all(urlList.map(URL => axios.get(URL)))
    .catch(error => {
        error.message = "There is a problem getting Axios array of promises " + error.message; // augment the error message ...
        throw error; // ... and re-throw the errror.
    });
};
```

And call as follows :

```
getallID().then(getData)
.then(resultData => {
    console.log(resultData);
}).catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
});
```

That will put you on solid ground but, on its own, is unlikely to fix a concurrency problem (if that's what it is), for which the simplest approach is to use [Bluebird's Promise.map](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) with the `concurrency` option.

The caller code can remain the same, just change `getData()`, as follows:

```
let getData = (urlList) => {
    let concurrency = 10; // play with this value to find a reliable concurrency limit
    return Promise.map(urlList, URL => axios.get(URL), {'concurrency': concurrency})
    .catch(error => {
        error.message = "There is a problem getting Axios array of promises " + error.message;
        throw error;
    });
};
// where `Promise` is Bluebird.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const axios = require('axios');
const axiosThrottle = require('axios-throttle'); 
//pass axios object and value of the delay between requests in ms
axiosThrottle.init(axios,200)
const options = {
  method: 'GET',
};
const urlList = [
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/3',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/4',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/5',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/6',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/7',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/8',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/9',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/10'
];
const promises = [];
const responseInterceptor = response => {
  console.log(response.data);
  return response;
};

//add interceptor to work with each response seperately when it is resolved
axios.interceptors.response.use(responseInterceptor, error => {
  return Promise.reject(error);
});

for (let index = 0; index < urlList.length; index++) {
  options.url = urlList[index];
  promises.push(axiosThrottle.getRequestPromise(options, index));
}

//run when all promises are resolved
axios.all(promises).then(responses => {
  console.log(responses.length);
});
```

https://github.com/arekgotfryd/axios-throttle